# Hibernate SQLINtegrityConstraintViolation / Duplicate Data Entry issue where upgrading my Spring Boot application

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to migrate from springBoot 2.5 to 2.7 and noticed that sometimes I encountered
SQLINtegrityConstraintViolation on duplicate data entry

[image: Error]

The code in where this error thrown out is here, a simple method where the record were retrieved and immediately saved. usually this method saves from 5 - 100 records each time it is triggered. It is not contains duplicate, as the collection being passed (rateIds) is actually a Set.

[image: code]

the called method
[image: caller method]

Upon debugging, we notice if :

1. we just save() the entity one by one, it does not return any issue.
2. Also, calling saveAll() will works but we have to commented this
   jpaProperties, hibernate.jdbc.batch_size , which previously we put in the order to increase performance. changing the size to 5, 10 does not work, although I noticed the documentation says it should be around 10-50.
   [image: jpa properties]

Any idea on why the spring batch updating does not work here?

Comment: Don't post images of code and logs. Copy the text instead and format it apropriately.

Comment: Noted, will fix it soon.